# "background: linear-gradient()" - what works in Chrome, does not in Safari

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to set a `linear-gradient` on a table row.

It works correctly in Chrome - the row is highlighted up to the required width:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

But it does not in Safari - Safari instead highlights every `<td>` cell instead of just `<tr>`:

[image: Safari sceenshot]

I am setting this programmatically via `style` property on a JSX element in a React application because the `percent` value is calculated on the fly and different for every row.

Code:

```
<tr style={{background: `linear-gradient(to right, ${color} ${percent}, transparent ${percent})`}}>
  <td>{value}</td>
  <td>{value}</td>
</tr>
```

In Chrome devtools I can see following being produced:

[image: Chrome devtools]

In Safari on the other hand:

[image: Safari devtools]

Anyone knows how to solve that?

Comment: How is the % calculated? That's the part that changes. Print out those numbers and see if they are the same on both browsers. By the result, it is most likely not the same

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=linear-gradient check this out, Safari has minimal support of this

Comment: @Huangism it does seem to be a known problem that the tds are given the background not the whole tr. It used to exist on other browsers but still persists in Safari.